# Android Edit text inside fragment tab keyboard not poping up

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a Tabview where i load different `Fragments` in one `Fragment` i have a `EditText` where i need the keyboard to automatically popup with out clicking the `EditText`.

I tried to set the focus manually through xml and even through code:

```
et.requestFocus();

<requestFocus />
```

but no use:

even i tried this:

```
etName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    ((InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(
                            etName, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
                }
            }
        });
```

where for the first time i dont see the keyboard even when i click the EditText, But when i switch tab and come back it works(the keyboard automatically pops up).

What is the issues here, i have some other edit text boxes in the project it automatically shows the keyboard even with out i set the focus. But here its strange. Is it some thing to do with the tabs?!

EDIT:

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="4dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Enter album name..." >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/createAlbum"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Create Album" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You need to have scrollView for the entire layout in order for the keyboard to take room

Comment: @Pragnani hi thanks for the reply,, i tried adding scroll view to my layout.. u can see the updated code above.. But unfortunately it dint work out!